# Bootstrap 4 seems just let me margin-left, not MARGIN-RIGHT?

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a div at bottom right. But I dont know which device screen will be (large or small), so I think I should margin-right: 100px; or something like that. I cannot margin-left: 900px or 400px because I dont know how large the device is.
I'm trying to set property css margin-right but not successfully.
This is my test code. Please help me out.
Similarly, margin-bottom looks illegal here.
[This picture shows my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcCza.jpg)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 .worldcup{
   margin-right: 40%;
 }
 .euro{
   margin-left: 40%;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body >

<div><p class="worldcup">worldcup</p></div>
<div><p class="euro">euro</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not bootstraps fault. You simply do not understand margins. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to set a <div> at bottom right. But I dont know which device screen will be (large or small), so I think I should margin-right: 10%; or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put text-align:right; it may solve your issue

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 .worldcup{
   margin-right: 40%;
 }
 .euro{
   margin-left: 40%;
text-align: right;
float: right;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body >

<div><button class="worldcup">worldcup</button></div>
<div><button class="euro">euro</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For button, it doesn't work. Float is quite complicate to me, (although I can float right, but float right with 100px far from right border???)

Comment: Thank you at first. I did it. And get some conclusions:
- class "euro" (text-align) in div tag works, no need float right.
- class "euro" (text-align) in button tag doesnot work, so it is right align due to float property.

Answer (score 0):

here is the bootstrap code for it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
  <html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="text-align: left">
          WORLDCUP
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="text-align: right">
          EURO
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Text-align works, thank you. And you remind me of using col-*. Appreciate it. Have a good day.

Comment: @Bootresappler  if you liked the answer you can give it a green tick on the left hand side